# MySQL - LOAD DATA LOCAL

Tags: python, mysql, linux, ubuntu

Running a MySQL (8.0) database on a Ubuntu (20.04) VPS. My current objective is trying to load a .CSV automatically into a table via a Python script. The script is theoretically correct and should work, it's the ability to process the data from the CSV into the table.

dbupdate.py:

```
import mysql.connector
import os
import string


db = mysql.connector.connect (
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="********",
    db="Rack_Info"
)

sqlLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/OSA_ADVA_Dashboard/Processed_CSV/DownloadedCSV.csv' INTO TABLE BerT FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '*' IGNORE 1 LINES;"

try:
    curs = db.cursor()
    curs.execute(sqlLoadData)
    db.commit()
    print ("SQL execution complete")
    resultSet = curs.fetchall()
except IOError:
    print ("Error incurred: ")
    db.rollback()
    db.close()

print ("Data loading complete.\n")
```

I have consulted the official documentation and enabled local_infile on both the server and client, configured the my.cnf and in SQL.

The my.cnf file:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[client]
local_infile=1

[mysql]
local_infile=1

[mysqld]
local_infile=1
```

I have restarted both php and MySQL services to no avail, as well as the server. At a loss here at what to do. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated the php.ini file and uncommented the load data lines, still nothing.

Turns out one of mysqld's variable, secure_file_priv, was pointing at an empty/default directory. All I had to do was change the directory to the where my files were located. All working now.

Answer (score 0):

if im not mistaken php has its own config file where you have to enable load data local infile